# What is the reason this Scala trait fails to compile?

Tags: scala, traits

I'm looking at the code from this blog post on [Phantom Types](http://james-iry.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/phantom-types-in-haskell-and-scala.html) which is reproduced [here](http://arnolddevos.github.io/phantom_types/#/) and [here](https://github.com/arnolddevos/phantom_types).

```
object RocketModule {

   sealed trait NoFuel
   sealed trait Fueled
   sealed trait NoO2
   sealed trait HasO2

   final case class Rocket[Fuel, O2] private[RocketModule]()

   def createRocket = Rocket[NoFuel, NoO2]()

   def addFuel[O2](x : Rocket[NoFuel, O2]) = Rocket[Fueled, O2]()

   def addO2[Fuel](x : Rocket[Fuel, NoO2]) = Rocket[Fuel, HasO2]()

   def launch(x : Rocket[Fueled, HasO2]) = "blastoff"

   implicit def toPiped[V] (value:V) = new {
      def |>[R] (f : V => R) = f(value)
   }
```

The particular line that puzzles me is this:

```
//This won't compile - there's no fuel
def test3 = createRocket |> addO2 |> launch
```

Now this code is making a point about extra information at compile time - and the virtues of Scala warning you up front. My question is: **What is the reason this Scala trait fails to compile?**

Comment: I'm having trouble deciphering the code from the command line. Could reformat?

Comment: The original post is literate code in both Haskell and Scala. The "> blah" lines are Haskell and can be ignored since he's asking about the Scala version.

Comment: Thanks James - much appreciated since I believe this was based on your blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read `test3 = createRocket |> addO2 |> launch` as:

```
val intermediateValue = createRocket |> addO2
val test3 = intermediateValue |> launch
```

`createRocket |> addO2` translates to `addO2(createRocket())`, which returns an intermediate value of type `Rocket[Fuel, HasO2]`. `intermediateValue |> launch` translates to `launch(intermediateValue)`. `launch` takes a parameter of type `Rocket[Fueled, HasO2]`, though; the call to `launch` won't compile because you've passed it the wrong type.